# Games crashes sometimes during restart

Tags: java, android, arraylist, crash, draw

Hello stackoverflow community, 
I need some help plz. This ConcurrentModificationException-error is making me crazy! I just recently started android game development and programming in general.

When i play my game its flawless but sometims if im trying to start a new game it crashes. Logcat show these two lines in my code but i dont know how to fix it because they look correct to me :/

```
public void run() {
    while (playing) {
        update();
        draw(); //the draw-method is marked
        control(); } }
```

and in my draw-method:

```
 // I draw the SpaceDust from an ArrayList
 paint.setColor(Color.argb(255, 255, 255, 255));
        for (SpaceDust sd : dustList) {
            canvas.drawPoint(sd.getX(), sd.getY(), paint); }
```

Any ideas?
Thanks Niclas

Edit: LogCat output

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-146798 
Process: niclas.spacegame, PID: 7983
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next(ArrayList.java:573)
at niclas.spacegame.GameActivity$TDView.update(GameActivity.java:285)
at niclas.spacegame.GameActivity$TDView.run(GameActivity.java:206)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Edit: update-method
     private void update() {
        boolean hitDetected = false;
        if(Rect.intersects(player.getHitbox(), enemy1.getHitbox())){
            hitDetected = true;
            enemy1.setX(-100);
        }
        if(Rect.intersects(player.getHitbox(), enemy2.getHitbox())){
            hitDetected = true;
            enemy2.setX(-100);
        }
        if(Rect.intersects(player.getHitbox(), enemy3.getHitbox())){
            hitDetected = true;
            enemy3.setX(-100);
        }
        if(screenX > 1000){
            if(Rect.intersects(player.getHitbox(), enemy4.getHitbox())){
                hitDetected = true;
                enemy4.setX(-100);
            }
        }
        if(screenX > 1200){
            if(Rect.intersects(player.getHitbox(), enemy3.getHitbox())){
                hitDetected = true;
                enemy5.setX(-100);
            }
        }
        if(hitDetected) {
            soundPool.play(bump, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
            player.reduceShieldStrength();
            if (player.getShieldStrength() < 0) {
                soundPool.play(destroyed, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
                gameEnded = true;
            }
        }

```
    player.update();
    enemy1.update(player.getSpeed());
    enemy2.update(player.getSpeed());
    enemy3.update(player.getSpeed());
    if(screenX > 1000) {
        enemy4.update(player.getSpeed());
    }
    if(screenX > 1200) {
        enemy5.update(player.getSpeed());
    }
    for (SpaceDust sd : dustList) {
        sd.update(player.getSpeed());
    }
    if(!gameEnded) {
        distanceRemaining -= player.getSpeed();
        timeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - timeStarted;
    }
    if(distanceRemaining < 0){
        soundPool.play(win, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1);
        if(timeTaken < fastestTime) {
            editor.putLong("fastestTime", timeTaken);
            editor.commit();
            fastestTime = timeTaken;
        }
        distanceRemaining = 0;
        gameEnded = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does `drawPoint` or anything it calls attempt to modify `dustList` ?

Comment: You forgot to add logcat.

Comment: post code from update method. Exception originate from update method.

Comment: Sometimes it runs 10games in a row and then suddenly it crashes :/ If i run the logcat again it points at the draw method. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably removing an element from the list whilst accessing it with a "for each" loop somewhere else.

Firstly, use an Iterator instead, but also wrap your access to the array list in a synchronized block:

Replace:

```
    for (SpaceDust sd : dustList) {
        sd.update(player.getSpeed());
    }
```

with:

```
synchronized(dustList){
        Iterator<SpaceDust> it = dustList.iterator();

        while (it.hasNext() {
           SpaceDust sd = it.next();
           sd.update(player.getSpeed());
        }
}
```

And wrap the list modifier in synchronized block:

```
synchronized(dustList){
    int numSpecs = 400;
    for (int i = 0; i < numSpecs; i++) { 
        SpaceDust spec = new SpaceDust(screenX, screenY); 
        dustList.add(spec); 
    } 
}
```

This approach is quite inefficient but it should solve your problem. This is locking the array list so it cannot be modified while you're reading or writing to it.

Comment: ok, would need to see more code to diagnose this then. Need to see any code that modifies your ArrayList

Comment: clearly you must be removing items from dustList somewhere in your code? Show us that code

Comment: Additionaly I have this for-loop in my code.                                                  int numSpecs = 400;
 for (int i = 0; i < numSpecs; i++) {
 SpaceDust spec = new SpaceDust(screenX, screenY);
 dustList.add(spec);
  }

Comment: How often is that code called? Do you have multiple threads? See my edit

Comment: Oh my god, it works!!!! Thank you very very very much!!!!!! I spended hours for finding a solution :)

Comment: Good stuff, please mark my answer as the solution :)